# Google Calendar API Javascript Quickadd

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-calendar-api

Trying to allow a user to authenticate and quickadd an event using the Google calendar API v3 with javascript. I dont see the authenticate button. I am very inexperienced with coding.

Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } test.html:47
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'qainput' of undefined test.html:62
onload test.html:62
```

html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <style>
      #info {
        border: 0px solid black;
        padding: 0.25em;
        margin: 0.5em 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var apiKey = 'AIzaSyDcbjOvAT85hCdVrjgUAqylf_QtxE2Gx60';
      var clientId = '202852486259.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
      }


      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        if (authResult) {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          makeApiCall();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      function makeRpcRequest() {
        var qatext = document.qaform.qainput.value;
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.quick_add({
          'calendarId': 'primary',
          'text': +qatext+
        });
        request.execute(writeResponse);
      }

      function writeResponse(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var name = response.summary;
        var infoDiv = document.getElementById('info');
        var infoMsg = document.createElement('P');
        infoMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(+ name' sucessfully created!'));
        infoDiv.appendChild(infoMsg);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="document.qaform.qainput.focus();">
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize to Use QuickAdd</button>
    <form id="qaform">
    <input placeholder='QuickAdd' name='qainput' />
    <button id="rpc" onclick="makeRpcRequest();">Add</button>
    </form>
    <div id="info"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `+qatext+` and `createTextNode(+ name' sucessfully created!')`?

Answer (score 1):

As its been a few weeks you've probably found your answer but I was having the same issue recently starting with basically the same code that you're using. I had simply not activated google calendar under "services" in the google console. If all of the console settings aren't correct, the "authorize" button remains hidden(it is hidden by default). Once all the settings are correct and the script is communicating properly with the api, the authorize button becomes visible and you can then add the event and write the response by clicking the button.